# How correctly shutdown those threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to make that OptionPanel makes threads shutdown themselves. I know it suppose to be done in the run method of the thread class but I don't know if I should to synchronize something there or not.

*How to make that these threads will shut themselves after clicking correct option in JOptionPanel?*

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Wat extends Thread {
    private char c;
    private int interv;
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public Wat(char c, int interv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.interv = interv;
    }

    public void run() {

        while (running) {
            try {
                System.out.println(c);
                Thread.sleep(interv * 100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wat w1 = new Wat('A', 3);
        Wat w2 = new Wat('B', 4);
        Wat w3 = new Wat('C', 5);
        w1.start();
        w2.start();
        w3.start();
        Object[] options = { "Shutdown A", "Shutdown B", "Shutdown C" };
        int option;
        while (w1.isAlive() || w2.isAlive() || w3.isAlive()) {
            option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                    "Which one would you like to shut?", "Threads",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);
            switch (option) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                w1.running = false;
                break;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                w2.running = false;
                break;
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                w3.running = false;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562720/how-to-access-the-running-thread-runnable.  use the technique there.

Comment: Here's information about how to interrupt a thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791361/thread-not-interrupting/9791479#9791479

Comment: I have edited my question is the code is correct now? Can it be done better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have:

```
Thread.sleep(interv * 100);
```

I would look at sending an [interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) to each thread. The interrupt will do just that to the `sleep()` method and it will be more responsive than the usual practise of looping around a boolean (e.g. `while (!done) {....}`).

As well as the tutorial linked above, check out this DeveloperWorks article on [handling InteruptedExceptions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html).

Comment: Isnt it considered bad practice to use Exceptions for control flow?

Comment: This interupt method did not work for me. I have edited my question is the code is correct now? Can it be done better?

Comment: @Brady - I wouldn't really class this as flow control. Besides, how would you interrupt a thread waiting on a socket or similar without such a mechanism.

Comment: A condition variable is a common mechanism to signal a thread, but then you would need some sort of while loop, which isnt necessarily bad. Its also quite common not to block waiting on a socket, but rather to call select() with a time-out value.